# Determine which website / IP is sending data to Google Analytics when the snippet isn't on our site

Tags: google-analytics

I recently updated a client's website with a brand new site design and realized several days later that this new design did not contain their Google Analytics tracking code.

For curiosities sake, I opened Google Analytics and to my surprise found that I was still receiving hits (although *very few*, ~10 a day).

How do I determine what is sending this data to GA? It certainly isn't my site. The URLs specified under the "Behavior > Site Content > All Pages" tab don't even exist on my site and the 404 page that comes up when I access them doesn't have GA tracking code on it.

Is there some way to view GA activity audit information or by some other means determine what is sending these hits?

Comment: It is spam bot traffic, just avoid it.

Comment: Interesting question, which leads me to think about a HYPOTHETICAL SITUATION. What if you hire an SEO company, and to show "how good their services worked" they simply took your analytics code, pasted it on one of their random site. That would then show more traffic in your (the clients) analytics report -- which they can then claim is because of their "great SEO techniques / services" makes sense...?

Answer (score 1):

You can check things like Bounce Rate, Pages/Session, and Avg. Session Duration, referrals (Acquisition > All Traffic > Referrals). If it's spam that you've identified, then you can follow this guide to combat it: http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/